# Validate if certificate is revoked

Tags: c#, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have the following situation:

- Java Applet for digital signature - on client side
- Validation of digital signature and digital certificate - on server side

I'm using the following C# code to validate the signature and the certificate:

```
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(pdf);
SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms(content, true);
signedMessage.Decode(assinatura);
signedMessage.CheckSignature(false);
```

Where:

- pdf - signed pdf file
- assinatura - pdf's signature - in my case, the signature it's not with the pdf file

By the tests I made, the code validate the certificate chain, the expiration and others...

However, I would like to know a few things:

This code validates that the certificate used for signing is revoked? If it does not validate, how could I make such a validation system at this point?

Is there a way to create a certificate that is revoked for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Revocation check is performed by

1. Obtaining CRL that can contain information about the status of the certificate
2. Sending OCSP request to the server authorized to respond to such requests

If OCSP server's URL is present, OCSP is the preferred (for security) method to check revocation, but in general both checks should be performed.

OCSP and CRL operations are supported by our SecureBlackbox, CryptLib, BouncyCastle. In SecureBlackbox you will find a high-level CertificateValidator class which does all checks for you (at the same time letting you interfere in all aspects of the procedure).

There's no way to create a revoked certificate unless you run your own private certificate authority (but if you did, probably there would be no question). The reason is that you can't put your certificate's ID to the CRL sent by CA (or make the third-party OCSP responder do this).

Oh, I can see one way - buy a certificate, then contact the CA and tell them that you've disclosed the private key. They will block the certificate. But this is quite costly method :).

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for take too long to answer! Too bad I can't easily test revoked certificates. =/

Comment: Can you tell me if the code line `signedMessage.CheckSignature(false);` already validate if the certificate is revoked? Or I need to implement some more code?